# Re authenticate github in gitkraken

Tags: git, github, gitlab, access-token, gitkraken

I am trying to re-authenticate my GitKraken with GitHub with my access token, since I used to be authenticated with user/password before, but now it is required to use personal access token. Can someone help me with that, I already have authenticated with the token in the terminal and I can do all git manipulations, however in gitkraken pull/push fails saying it cannot connect to origin and I am not asked to re-auth my github account

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 3):

[image: gitkraken github]

What version of your GitKraken?

latest version of GitKraken only can authenticating via Browser

via Preference -> Integrations -> GitHub

Comment: This assumes that a user only has 1 PAT for every repository he/she works with while the reality is that while participating (which is quite the fundamental principle behind git) you will end up with lots of different and granular PAT. As of today I can't find any way to register multiple PAT and even worse, update the one stored in case old one expires.

Comment: For now, GitKraken has profile feature. It allow to adding multiple account e.g github, gitlab, etc by switching between profiles.